# Multiple authentication filters with shiro

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, shiro

I implemented a custom authentication filter with shiro, but would like to use basic authentication as a backup option. This means - if the user has the right credentials for my custom filter, he will be logged in. If not, I would like to check if the user provided basic authc header.

This is my `shiro.ini`

```
[main]
myAuthc = com.company.security.MyAuthcFilter
myRealm = com.company.security.MyAuthcRealm
myRealm.authenticationTokenClass = com.company.security.MyAuthcToken
securityManager.realms = $myRealm

# user for the basic authc filter
[users]
testuser = testpass

[urls]
/web/** = myAuthc, authcBasic
```

The problem is that `myAuthc` gets evaluated, `authcBasic` not!
In my test case, the client only supplies the basic authentication header, which means that `myAuthc` will not authenticate the user. I thought, that the next filter in the chain will be evaluated, but this does not happen!

In the test scenario, both `isAccessAllowed()` and `onAccessDenied()` methods of `myAuthc` return `false`.

BTW, when I request `/web/hello`, I actually receive `HTTP 200`, but with an empty response body - without the information that would come from the `hello` resource.

Is it possible to combine filters like this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `permissive` option: https://shiro.apache.org/spring-boot.html#annotations-and-web-applications

So your *config* would look something like this:

`/web/** = myAuthc[permissive], authcBasic`

Of course, this depends on what your actual `MyAuthcFilter` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, `onAccessDenied()` should return `true` for the filter chain to continue.